# How to solve linear recurrences involving two functions?

Tags: c++, algorithms, dynamic-programming

Actually I came across a question in Dynamic Programming where we need to find the number of ways to tile a 2 X N area with tiles of given dimensions..
[Here is the problem statement](http://www.lightoj.com/volume_showproblem.php?problem=1244)

Now after a bit of recurrence solving I came out with these.
F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) + 2G(n-1), and
G(n) = G(n-1) + F(n-1)

I know how to solve LR model where one function is there.For large N as is the case in the above problem we can do the matrix exponentiation and achieve O(k^3log(N)) time where k is the minimum number such that for all k>m F(n) does not depend on F(n-k). The method of solving linear recurrence with matrix exponentiation as it is given in [that blog](http://fusharblog.com/solving-linear-recurrence-for-programming-contest/).

Now for the LR involving two functions can anyone suggest an approach feasible enough for large N.

Comment: [link](http://fusharblog.com/solving-linear-recurrence-for-programming-contest/). This is the blog i got the basics from..

Comment: instead of posting a link, consider giving readers a brief explanation / summary of what is relevant to the question asked at that link

Comment: Actually i just wanted to point out the method of solving linear recurrence with matrix exponentiation as it is given in that blog. Nevertheless I feel I have clearly stated the question.The guy knowing the method would not even require the link!!

Comment: the link behind "[Here is the problem statement](http://www.lightoj.com/volume_showproblem.php?problem=1244)" doesn't show anything without login, what is in there?

Answer (score 1):

Same method works: find a matrix that translates `(F(n-1) F(n-2) G(n-1))` into `(F(n) F(n-1) G(n))`. A `((1 1 2) (1 0 0) (1 0 1))` matrix would do it.

**Explanation**

That's how matrix-by-vector multiplication works. A *first* element of a resulting vector is an inner product of a *first* row and an initial vector:

```
1*F(n-1) + 1*F(n-2) + 2*G(n-1)
```

which according to recurrence *is* `F(n)`. Same goes for the *second* and *third*.

Comment: Could you explain your answer in more detail please. I, for one, would like to know why this answers the question.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman See update

Comment: Usually the next step is a Eigen-value/Eigen-vector decomposition of the matrix, after which an explicit formula for F(n) and G(n) can be derived.